# Discord.py await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a blacklist filter for my discord.py discord bot.

My Goal:

When a word that is listed in *blacklist.txt* is said in a message,

1. The bot deletes the message
2. Sends a dm to the user saying they were muted
3. Sends a message in the channel
4. Removes the member role and OG role from the user
5. Applies the mute role and logs this in a set channel.

My plan is to have an effective and working blacklist.

The result I am currently getting:

1. The message with the blacklisted word is being deleted

**2) No role changes are occurring**

**3) No messages are being sent in the server nor in dm and the logging is not working.**

This is the error message I am currently getting:

```
line 720, in remove_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I am using pycharm and the line

```
await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
```

Is from the library, rather than my main code.

Here is the code I am currently using to do this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f'{message.channel}: {message.author}: {message.content}')
    with open('blacklist.txt', 'r') as f:
        blacklist = f.read().splitlines()
        for word in blacklist:
            if word in message.content:
                await message.delete()
                mutedRole = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="MUTED")
                member = message.author
                memberRole = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Member")
                OGRole = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="OG (Joined Under 1k)")
                await member.remove_roles(memberRole)
                await member.remove_roles(OGRole)
                await member.add_roles(mutedRole)
                await message.channel.send(f'Muted {member.mention}')
                await message.author.send(f'You were muted in the server {message.guild.name}.')
                embed = discord.Embed(title="\u200b", color=0x008000)
                mute_embed = discord.Embed(
                    colour=discord.Color.red()
                )
                mute_embed.add_field(name=f'Mute applied to {message.author}', value=f'Muted Permanently')
                channel = bot.get_channel(759441424524509185)
                await channel.send(embed=mute_embed)
            else:
                pass
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Methods I have tried:

1. Reading the discord.py docs
2. Asking for help on discord.py help servers
3. Debugging the code using pycharm.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If you're sending a message in DMs, the `guild` attribute is `None`, makes sense.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Can you expand on this please and what I need to change in the code to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error msg you're getting indicates that the `role` object has value `None`, so have you tried debug printing the `memberRole` and `OGRole` objects before calling on `remove_roles` to see that you're sending what you expect to send?